# Var in greasemonkey fails passing to the attribute

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Hi there I'm not really an expert in Javascript and noobie in gresemonkey and I'll need your help.
So here is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Button RT
// @include     *rt*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
// create button
var anid= document.getElementsByClassName( 'value id' )[ 0 ].innerHTML;
var btn = document.createElement( 'input' );
with( btn ) {
  setAttribute( 'onclick', 'window.open(http://www.google.com"+ anid)    ');
  setAttribute( 'value', 'Button!' );
  setAttribute( 'type', 'button' );
}
// append at end
document.getElementsByClassName( 'value id' )[ 0 ].parentNode.appendChild( btn );
```

So what am I doing wrong? because anid variable appears as anid in the onclick event and not as what it should. What am I missing?
I'm getting something like this from firebug

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open("http://www.google.com"+ ticketid) " value="Button!!">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setAttribute( "onclick", "window.open('http://www.google.com'" + anid + ")");`

Comment: It didn't work either. I had to change it to `'window.open("http://www.google.com'+anid+'" )')` and now it works

Comment: See? Now we both managed to screw up on the same thing. A good practise in order to avoid these kind of mistakes is: var server = "http://www.google.com"; var myUrl = anid;  var completeUrl = server+myUrl;

Comment: Hey yes. I even tried that but it didn't work for some reason :/